# When do the operations $\int$, $\lim$, and $d(\cdot)/dx$ preserve the direction of inequality?

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $f$ and $g$ be a functions where $\int$, $\lim$, $d(\cdot)/dx$ are well defined on their whole domain and they both have the same domain.

Also suppose that:

$f(x) \leq g(x)$  for all $x$ in their domain

My question is:

Does inequality above imply that:

- $\displaystyle\int_A f(x) \, dx \leq \int_A g(x) \, dx$, where $A$ is a subset of the given domain.
- $\displaystyle\int f(x) \, dx \leq \int g(x) \, dx$
- $\displaystyle\frac{df(x)}{dx}\leq \frac{dg(x)}{dx}$
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x) \leq \lim_{x\rightarrow a} g(x)$, $a$ is any point in domain

And assuming that the operations on left and right side of the below inequalities exists:

- $\displaystyle\int_{A_\infty}f(x) \, dx \leq \int_{A_\infty} g(x) \, dx$, where $A_\infty$ might be $(-\infty,a)$, $(a,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,\infty)$
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x) \leq \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} g(x)$
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} f(x) \leq \lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} g(x)$

I'd also like to know if it holds for $\geq$, $<$, $>$.

Comment: Not true for derivatives, for integrals this holds in the Lebesgue case.

Comment: I was confused by the title and made an edit. Feel free to change it if I mis-characterized your intent.

Answer (score -1):

Since $f(x)\leq g(x)$ then $f(x)-g(x)\leq 0$. So $\int_A f(x)-g(x) dx\leq 0$ or $\int_A f(x) dx\leq \int_A g(x) dx$.
Now, if $f(x)=sin(x)$ and $g(x)=1$ obviously $f\leq g$ but $\frac{df}{dx}=cos(x)$ and $\frac{dg}{dx}=0$ so $f'$ is not less or equal to $g'$ for every $x\in$Domain$(f)\cap$Domain$(g)$.
Finally, this property of limits holds.

Comment: Why did the inequality direction not change when you used integral on both sides?